# Why is running django app in cmd giving me a module error?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

each time I try to run my django app it is giving me this error( ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.genresdjango')

The genres is the page iam trying to create

I tried removing the line from the django settings.py it is running perfectly but when i add the line for my app it is not

Comment: If you're trying to create it, why is it in `django.contrib`?